# Trigonometry - Problems in 3 Dimensions

Tags: trigonometry

So my question is that I've been given the following question, but some of it doesn't make sense ...

A person stands on a 15m diving board. On his left is his coach, who looks up at him from the ground at a 28 degree angle, while his parents are on his right looking up from the ground at a 25 degree angle. If the angle of the platform between his coach and his parents is 95 degrees, how far apart are they?

My  question basically is that is the 95 made with the ground? Also, how is it relevant in finding the distance? I thought you could just solve how far the parents are from the board using tangent (15/tan25, 15/tan28), and do the same for the coach and then add the distance. But this seems deceptively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal distance $c$ of the coach is $c = 15 / tan(25) = 32.168$

The horizontal distance $p$ of the parents is $p = 15 / tan(28) = 28.211$

The angle (in the xy plane) between coach and parents is $95$.

The square of the distance $d$ between coach and parents is given by the cosine rule

$d^2 = c^2 + p^2 − 2*c*p*cos(95)$

So

$d^2 = 32.168^2 + 28.211^2 - 2 * 32.168 * 8.211 * cos(95)$

$d^2 = 1876.68$

Which gives $d = 43.32$

Comment: alright this much makes perfect sense. However, can you explain why we use cos law instead of just adding together horizontal distances?

Comment: The two horizontal distances are two sides of the triangle between which the angle is $95$. It would only make sense to add the two distances if the angle between them is $180$. That is a special case of the cosine rule, where adding the lengths gives the same result as applying the cosine rule. In this case the angle is $95$, so adding the lengths won't give the right distance. Here is a [basic example](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sas-triangles.html).

Comment: To explain further, suppose coach and parents are standing in the **same place**. The distance between them is $0$ so adding their (equal) horizontal distance from the diving board gives the wrong answer. The angle between them must be considered too.

Comment: That last part was quite helpful. Appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking down on a plan view, you have a triangle with the three vertices as the coach, the diver and the parents. The angle at the diver is $95$ deg, the ground length c of the side from diver to coach is $\frac{15}{\tan(28)}$ and the ground length p of the side from diver to parents is $\frac{15}{\tan(25)}$. The ground length x of the side from coach to parents is therefore $x = \sqrt{(c^2 + p^2 - 2\cdot p\cdot c\cdot  cos(95))}$.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense for the most part. However, why is the 95 degree relevant? How come you use cosine law instead of just adding up c and p? Is it because of the elevation?

Comment: It's because the 3 are not in a straight line. That is, the angle between the coach and parents isn't 180 deg it's 95 degrees. The question says the coach to the left but it is more accurate to say to the left and forward of the diver and for the parents to the right and forward of the diver. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense. Much appreciated